# A question about EtherZero

Tags: private-key, hardforks

I'm reading about the hard fork EtherZero, in particular the section about how to get ETZ money.

Can someone explain me what does it means "Derive the private key from the private key-approving wallets, then import the private key account to the official EtherZero wallet to get EtherZero." and how to import this derived private key into EtherZero wallet?

Thank you.

Comment: Very very suspicious.. The github account pointed in their page doesn't belong to them, there's zero code. If you plan to fork you need a lots of testing.

Comment: You are right. I didn't notice that. I'll wait to see what will happen. Thank you

Comment: Any update on this fork and how to get into the ICO?

Comment: This isn't an answer and should be a comment or a new question.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17594)